# Using pair in variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, visual-c++-2015

Okay, I'm trying to implement a range tree in n-dimensions using variadic templates.  I have the basic setup working, but I want to be able to optionally pass a compare function object in the template list to sort the tree by something other than std::less.

My first thought is that I could overload the template list with a version that includes a pair as the first element, with the pair containing the type and the compare funcition.  But I can't see to get the template declaration line to compile.  Visual C++ (2015) starts with C2079: "std::pair::first uses undefined class 'T'".

Anyways, on to the code.  Here's a 
small snippet to show what I'm trying to do:

```
template <class... Args> class rangetree{
};

template <class T, class... Args> class rangetree<T, Args...> {
public:
  map <T, rangetree<Args...> * > tree;
};
```

This all works normally.  But when I add another version of rangetree, with a pair as the first template member, I have problems:

```
template <pair<class T, class Compare>, class... Args> class rangetree<pair<T, Compare>, Args...>{
public:
  map <T, rangetree <Args...> *, Compare> tree;
};
```

This is the part I can seem to get formatted in a way that the compiler is happy.  The idea is to optionally pair template members with compare functions if something other than less should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
template <class T, class Compare, class... Args>
class rangetree<pair<T, Compare>, Args...>
{
    ...
};
```

---

Alternatively, if all you're doing here is providing the ability to add a comparator, you can outsource this work to a metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
struct range_types {
    using key = T;
    using compare = std::less<T>;
};

template <typename T, typename Comp>
struct range_types<pair<T, Comp>>
{
    using key = T;
    using compare = Comp;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
class rangetree<T, Args...>
{
    map <typename range_types<T>::key,
         rangetree <Args...> *,
         typename range_types<T>::compare
         > tree;
};
```